# Appinventor programm solution with VirtualScreens

Tags: android

how can I open directly the one of Layout (Virtual Screen )in the Screen1  from other Screen, if I have used multiple Layouts in Screen1 as Virtual Screen

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Answer (score 0):

your question is too broad but from what you are saying you are either looking for
include tag in xml like:

```
<include
 layout="your_layout.xml"
 />
```

or  switch to Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, theActivityYouWantToGoTo.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

you really need to look into some tutorials I would suggest
newBoston's Android tutorial on YouTube.